# Why is gets not modified to make it non exploitable?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

There are many non safe functions in C like gets,printf and others.
When these vulnerabilities are well known, why haven't the functions been modified to make them safe?

Comment: Because there are already alternatives like `fgets()`? And there is a safer function called `gets_s`

Comment: Because there a millions of lines of code that rely on the current behavior, and changing it would break them all.

Comment: Entirely overhauling C's string handling could work (but since C has no native 'string' type, that in itself is unfeasible). Currently, there is no way for `gets` itself to find out where its argument is pointing to and how much space there actually is reserved.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: purely as the devil's advocate, I could submit that all those millions of lines of code are already broken *because* they use `gets`!

Comment: @CoolGuy there indeed are alternatives. My worry was for existing code being vulnerable as well. Why not correct those methods rather than everyone having to update their code or take care in their code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, you can't change a function's signature (i.e. the number and type of the arguments) without breaking existing code.

Vulnerable functions tend to get fixed by introducing alternatives that have additional arguments (such as buffer sizes). These alternative functions are designed to be non-exploitable when used correctly.

Compare, for example, [`sprintf()` and `snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Comment: And [sprintf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx) and [snprintf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f30dzcf6.aspx).  They're actually defined in C11's Annex K, but I'm not sure about how widely available they are, not to mention the fact that they're optional rather than required.